# How I add bracket in string variable in TCL file

Tags: tcl

I have written one TCL script but I have one problem when making a string variable as below:

```
set a 100
set b "this is variable[$a]"
```

I want b to be assign with b = "`this is variable[100]`" but I got the error:

```
invalid command name 100
```

Please help me to fix it :-(.

Comment: See the [12 syntax rules of Tcl](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), particularly rule #7

Answer (score 3):

You just need to escape it:

```
set a 100
set b "this is variable\[$a\]"
```

Comment: technically, we only need to escape the opening bracket.

Comment: Thank you very much.My problem was I use the tool which is same as TCL but it don't accept \[ and \] as string "[]".

Comment: It looks like you're misnuderstanding what's happening. It's not that Tcl dont' accept "[]". The problem is that "[something]" in Tcl means you want to run the function/proc/command `something` and then insert it into the string. So to stop Tcl from thinking you want to execute `something` you need to tell it that `[` does not mean you want to call a function/command/proc.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities (but escaping the brackets is better):

```
set b [format {this is variable[%d]} $a]
set b [subst -nocom -noback {this is variable[$a]}]
```

Documentation:
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed it by using set b [format {this is variable[%d]} $a].